# NHibernate.Mapping Exception. No persister for Namespace.className

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

Have looked at 4 stackoverflow posts on the same issue but couldn't find a solution.

My main program:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema;
using NHibernate.Dialect;

namespace NhibernateORM
{
    public class Layout
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double xCoordinate { get; set; }
        public double yCoordinate { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static int getDummyTableSize(ISession session)
        {
            ITransaction readTx = session.BeginTransaction();
            int size = session.CreateSQLQuery(@"select * from mydb.mytable").List<object>().Count;
            readTx.Rollback();
            return size;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "hibernate.cfg.xml"));

            ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            ISession session = factory.OpenSession();

            int countBefore = getDummyTableSize(session);

            ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
            Layout d = new Layout();
            d.Id = 213;
            d.Name = "hello";
            d.xCoordinate = 25.823;
            d.yCoordinate = 746.2;

            // POINT OF ERROR 
            session.Save(d);
            tx.Commit();

            if (countBefore + 1 == getDummyTableSize(session))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("woo hoo");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("oh no");
            }
            session.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

My `hibernate.cfg.xml` (config file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">
      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Server=localhost;Database=mydb;User="root";
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    </property>
    <!--<mapping assembly="NhibernateORM"/>-->
    <!-- mapping files -->
    <!--<mapping resource="Mapping.hbm.xml" />-->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and my `Mapping.hbm.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NhibernateORM" auto-import="true">
  <class name="Layout" table="mytable">
   <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int">
   </id> 
   <property name="Name" column="name" 
             type="String"></property>
  <property name="xCoordinate" column="xCoordinate" 
             type="double"></property>
<property name="yCoordinate" column="yCoordinate" 
             type="double"></property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I tried the following:

1. Set build action of mapping file(`Mapping.hbm.xml`) to embedded resource and build action of config file (`hibernate.cfg.xml`) to embedded resource and content. Also set copy to output directory to copy always.
2. Set auto-import in hibernate-mapping tag to both true and false
3. Add mapping assembly tag in `hibernate.cfg.xml`, also checked the namespace and assembly name.
4. Adding a mapping resource tag in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file which gives an error of ambiguous mapping tag.

What more can I try? The error arises just before session.save() line, and the query retrieving count of rows in the table above session.save works fine.

Additionally following is the full error message:

```
NHibernate.MappingException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232832
  Message=No persister for: NhibernateORM.Layout
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName, Object obj)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
       at NhibernateORM.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\codebase\NhibernateORM\NhibernateORM\Program.cs:line 57
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say, because all that information, we should have a culprit. There are so many issues *(well **problems** in fact)* with the **mapping** and **C# code**, that we for sure know:

> the `Mapping.hbm.xml` is not correctly configured, not used, not visible for NHibernate

In case, that this file *as is* would be available to NHibernate session factory, we would get this Exception

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Instance' threw an exception. ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: NhibernateORM.Mapping.hbm.xml ---> NHibernate.MappingException: persistent class Layout, NhibernateORM not found ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type **'Layout'** from assembly 'NhibernateORM...

Which could be fixed by adding namespace attribute to mapping **`namespace="NhibernateORM"`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
  assembly="NhibernateORM"
  namespace="NhibernateORM"
  auto-import="true">
  <class name="Layout" table="mytable">
    <id name="Id" column="ID" type="int" generator="assigned" />
    <property name="Name"        column="name"        type="String"/>
    <property name="xCoordinate" column="xCoordinate" type="double" />
    <property name="yCoordinate" column="yCoordinate" type="double" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Once that would be fixed, we would later get this exception

> NHibernate.InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used as proxies:
>   NhibernateORM.Layout: method **get_Id** should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'...

which could be fixed by making all the Entity stuff virtual:

```
namespace NhibernateORM
{
    public class Layout
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual double xCoordinate { get; set; }
        public virtual double yCoordinate { get; set; }
```

So, for sure, we know - the issue is

- wrong configuration in the **`hibernate.cfg.xml`**
- wrong configuration of the **`Mapping.hbm.xml`** properties

This should be part of the *hibernate.cfg.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
      ...
      <mapping assembly="NhibernateORM"/>
```

the *hibernate.cfg.xml* must have properties:

- Build Action === Content
- Copy to Output Directory === Copy always

the *Mapping.hbm.xml* must have properties:

- Build Action === Embedded Resource
- Copy to Output Directory === Do not copy

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: in that case, please, check that your file is **really** having extension **`.hbm.xml`**. I remember once I had a typo ... e.g. just *.xml* ... and could not find out why is that mapping not loading... AND if that won't help, try to use explicit file loading with your config object -  `config.AddDirectory()` or `config.AddFile()` ... this way you will know, that file was processed (place that mapping file to some share, and loaded as xml file)